# Help with Reduction of Order differential equation problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a little confused how to solve these problems. They are under **miscellaneous problems** of chapter 2.9 in our textbook, but the **second order differential equations** don't start until chapter 3. The only instructions on how to solve these problems are provided below. I have to use some kind of substitution?

***Equations with the Dependent Variable Missing**. For a second order differential equation of the form y''=f(t,y'), the substitution v=y', v'=y'' leads to a ﬁrst order equation of the form v'=f(t,v). If this equation can be solved for v, then y can be obtained by integrating dy/dt=v. Note that one arbitrary constant is obtained in solving the ﬁrst order equation for v, and a second is introduced in the integration for y.*

1. $t^2y''+2ty'-1=0$,  $t>0$ (**Solution**: $y = c_1t^{-1}+c_2+ln(t)$)
2. $ty''+y'=1$, $t>0$ (**Solution**: $y = c_1ln(t)+c_2+t$)
3. $t^2y''=(y')^2$ , $t>0$ (**Solution**: $c_1^2y=c_1t-ln|1+c_1t|+c_2$)

**Update**: Included solutions if that helps.

Comment: See Update 2 for the last constant $c_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can transform a second order differential equation of the form $y''=f(t,y')$, using the substitution $v=y', v'=y''$, to a ﬁrst order equation of the form $v'=f(t,v)$.

Lets do $(3)$ as an example, so we have:

$t^2y''=(y')^2$ , $t>0$

Let: $v=y', v'=y''$, yielding (notice that we have a form $v' = f(t, v)$):

$$t^2 v' = (v)^2$$

We can easily separate this as:

$$\tag 1 \frac{dv}{v^2} = \frac{dt}{t^2}$$

**Update**

From $(1)$, we get:

$$\frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{t} + c_1$$

This can be written as: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1 + c_1t}{t}$, and then we solve for $v$, yielding:

$$v = \frac{t}{1+c_1t}$$

However, from our earlier substitution, we have $v = y'$, so:

$$y' = \frac{t}{1+c_1t}$$

Can you solve for $y$ now?

**Update 2**

Note: when you solve for $y'$, you'll get another constant $c_2$ from that, to go along with the $c_1$. You would need to be given some ICs to figure those out - so they are left in this form.

Regards

Comment: I integrated both sides and got $v^{-1}=t^{-1}+c$. That seems to be not even close to the solution from the textbook.

Comment: @BluePonyInc.: recall, you substituted, so you have to work all the way up the food chain to get back to the solution. This was the first step. Clear?

Comment: I am still unsure. Could you please just finish problem #3 so I could see how it's done from start to finish and try to do the rest myself based off (3).

Comment: @BluePonyInc.: see update.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just have to integrate y'. I am still confused about "solve for v". It's basic Algebra, yet I don't know how did you get v=t/1+ct. How do you generally go from 1/v=1/t+c to v=t/1+ct?

Comment: See update - just use a common denominator of $t$ on the right hand side of the equation, and then solve for $v$. Have fun with the other tools - now you have all the tools needed to do those! Regards

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, where does second constant $c_2$ come from?

Comment: @amWhy: I like when you get that interaction, although it is a bit frowned upon. Regards